# Renaming a File

Tags: c#, file-rename

Guys I am trying to remane a file (adding _DONE to its name)

my researches showed that File.move(OLDNAME,NEWNAME) is what I needed.
Thus,
I did,

```
try
{
    string oldname = name;
    //XYZ_ZXX_ZZZ
    string newName = ToBeTested + "_DONE.wav";
    //rename file
    //NOTE : OldName is already in format XYZ_III_SSS.wav
    File.Move(oldname, newName);

}
catch (Exception exRename)
{
    string ex1 = exRename.ToString();
    //logging an error 
    string m = "File renaming process failed.[" + ex1 + "]";
    CreateLogFile(p, m);
}
```

But It does not bears any result (File is not renamed) but the exception is logged.

as such

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\Yachna\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FolderMonitoringService_RCCM\FolderMonitoringService_RCCM\bin\Debug\54447874_59862356_10292013_153921_555_877_400_101.wav'.
File name: 'C:\Users\Yachna\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FolderMonitoringService_RCCM\FolderMonitoringService_RCCM\bin\Debug\54447874_59862356_10292013_153921_555_877_400_101.wav'
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at RCCMFolderMonitor.Monitor.OnChanged(Object source, FileSystemEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Yachna\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\FolderMonitoringService_RCCM\RCCMFolderMonitor\Monitor.cs:line 209]
```

What did i do wrong ?

Comment: Have u checked the path to the old file?

Comment: File not exists at your old location..

Comment: Do I have to pass the path as parameter or the name of the file only.I passed only the name like this (xyz_iii_oiu_ghfd.wav). Is this wrong ?

Comment: What is RCCMFolderMonitor.Monitor ? Are you trying to move a file while you are looking for changes inside a FileSystemWatcher event?

Comment: [C# How to: Copy, Delete, and Move Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148994.aspx) If I were you I would check how are you passing the path, if youre using '' or "", the spaces of the path...

Comment: @Steve ,Yes exactly (but not moving only renaming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the file does not exist in the same folder as the application.

You will have to include the path in addition to the filename.

```
File.Move(path + oldname, path + newName);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the StackTrace it seems that you are trying to move/rename the file whilst you receive the OnChanged event of a FileSystemWatcher component. If this is true this means that another application is writing/changing the file that you are trying to move/rename.
This could result in the above error message. The file exists, but you cannot get access to it until the other application closes it.

Answer (score 1):

Without including the path of your file, Visual Studio looks for the file in your Debug directory. This is the reason of the error.

You have to include the full path of your file using the method [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) of System.IO namespace:

```
string myDirectory = @"C:\Files";

string myFileName = "myFile.wav";
string myNewFileName = "myFileNew.wav";

string myFileFullPath = Path.Combine(myDirectory, myFileName); 
string myNewFileFullPath = Path.Combine(myDirectory, myNewFileName); 

Console.WriteLine(myFileFullPath); // it writes to Console: C:\Files\myFile.wav

//Then you can rename the file
File.Move(myFileFullPath, myNewFileFullPath);
```